# Swift SpriteKit Local Variable

Tags: swift, variables, sprite-kit

I have a local variable named `bomb tower`. Code below:

```
if checkMark.contains(touchLocation) {
        let bombTowerLevel1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bomb tower trial 2")
        bombTowerLevel1.name = "bomb tower" //change later maybe
        bombTowerLevel1.position = bombTowerGhost.position
        bombTowerLevel1.zPosition = 1 //change later for health
        bombTowerLevel1.setScale(frame.size.height/2500)
        self.addChild(bombTowerLevel1)
}
```

I access it later using the `name` here:

```
func turretShoot() {
    let bombTower = self.childNode(withName: "bomb tower") as! SKSpriteNode
    bombTower.zRotation = mainturret.zRotation
    }
```

Let me be clear that there can be more than one bomb tower in the scene at one time therefore I didn't make `bomb tower` a global variable. The problem with the current code is that when I place more than one bomb tower, the action in the function is only preformed by the first bomb tower placed. Any ideas on how to make access the local variable and get every single bomb tower to turn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use SKNode’s `enumerateChildNodesWithName` instead to set the rotation all the nodes with the name:

```
func turretShoot() {
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "bomb tower") {
        node, stop in
        if let bombTower = node as? SKSpriteNode {
            bombTower.zRotation = mainturret.zRotation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. It's quite typical to create sprites in SK (via `let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(...`) and then set them free to live, and die in the scene with no need to retain that `mySprite` variable. Then, as Gary shows above, if you do need to do something to the sprite, you can pick it up using `enumerateChildNodes` (or various other methods) to once again connect the sprite in the scene to a local variable in your code so you can access the sprite's properties.

Comment: I'm getting an error that says "value type '(string) -> SKNode?' has no member 'enumerateChildNodes"' How do I get around this?